# Should we start a new Angular project with AngularDart (considering Angular 2.0)?

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

In this document:

http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/angular-20.html

It says:

> How does AngularJS 2 relate to AngularDart? When porting AngularJS to
>   the Dart language, we build a new version of Angular using all the
>   learnings we’d acquired to date.  Many of the improvements discussed
>   in this document like improved Directive concepts and syntax and
>   class/annotation-based DI are already present there.
>
> While the implementation isn’t what we’ll arrive at for 2, it’s a
>   great preview of what’s to come.
>
> We’ll be upgrading AngularDart as we build AngularJS 2 so folks who
>   prefer the Dart language can enjoy the same benefits as folks on JS. 
>   Our goal is that there will be a single framework with your choice of
>   language.

We are starting a new Angular project, given the above, would it be better to use AngularDart?

We have considered React+Flux+... but we like the templating of Angular.

Thanks,
Ashley.

Answer (score 1):

The angular team has stated at the ng-europe conference, videos are at angularjs .org, that if you are starting a project now, to use 1.3. This version will be supported and developed for the forseeable future.

2.0 is still in early days. The APIs are nowhere near finalized. They have taken ideas and concepts from AngularDart, but the implications are vastly different. I would speculate that the team will put more effort into an upgrade path for 1.3 rather than a conversion path for AngularDart.

Just be sure to follow the style guide to help make your code future friendly. https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide/blob/master/README.md

Tl;dr
Controllers and services are classes. Use ControllerAs syntax.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I understand 1.3 will be supported for 18-24 months. I was just intrigued by the statements above about AngularDart.  Note they said that they will be upgrading AngularDart.  So seeing as we are starting fresh, I thought that using AngularDart may perhaps be a slightly more appropriate choice. I hear what you say about the conversion path though - it will surely be where most users are, i.e. AngularJS.

Comment: It was stated that upgrading from Angular.dart 1.0 to Angular.dart 2.0 should be easy. I haven't read about anyone using Angular.dart 2.0 yet though.

Comment: Thanks Gunter - probably not many resources for Angular.Dart projects (e.g. I was interested in Foundation for Apps).  Oh well, looks like I will be using React.JS.